# I want print the square of each number on a separate line

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
def square_non (n):
    for x in range(0,21):
         if x < n:
             return (x*x)
         else:
            return "Please try again!"
```

Tried to debug but I don't comprehend why the for-loop isn't continuing.

Update: Just used list-comprehension and generators, which made the whole thing easy

Comment: return will end your function directly.

Comment: use print() instead of return, or append all the 'x' into a list and return the list

Comment: `yield` the result instead of `return`ing it

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I was initially trying to call the function and print it in that manner, therefore I used return.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks a lot for your help!! So, I decided just to use generators and get over with it xD ```def square_non (n):
    for i in n:
        yield (i*i)

a = square_non([1,2,3,4])
for num in a:
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the values, you should not return them but print them.

```
def square_non (n):
    for x in range(0,21):
         if x < n:
             print(x*x)
         else:
             print("Please try again!")
```

If you return `x*x`, this function will terminate at the moment it reaches this return statement, which is in the first run of the loop. So, the function just returns 0, no matter what you pass as an argument.

Comment: The thing is I'm also getting "None" printed in the output, which I'm guessing is because of "break", any change that I could make there?

Comment: No, it's because `square_non` returns `None` (every function that does not explicitly a value does), so `a` is `None`. Simply don't print `a`.

Comment: @Jasmijn could you please explain a bit more about the None part?

Comment: Not sure what there is to explain. Every function returns a value. If a function returns by "falling out" of the bottom rather than coming across an explicit `return x`, the value it returns is `None`. Basically, imagine every function having a line `return None` at the end: if it doesn't return anything else, it will return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Return will end the execution of loop and will return control to calling function. So best way is to get all values in array and return it.

Try this code:

```
def square_non (n):
    squares = [] 
    for x in range(0,21):
         if x < n:
             squares.append(x*x)
         else:
             return squares

def calling_function():   #Function from which it get called
    squares = square_non(10) #Assume 10 for example 
    for square in squares:
        print(str(square) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the value in seperate line then simple use `print(square_non(n),'\n')` and add `'\n'` which will create new line.

> Here is the code

```
def square_non (n):
    for x in range(0,21):
         if x < n:
             return (x*x)
         else:
            return "Please try again!"
print(square_non(n),'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned in the comments already the issue here is the return because a loop as soon as hits a return it will terminate it.

The most simple fix for your code would be this --->:

```
def square_non(n):

for x in range(0, 21):
    
    if x < n:
        print(x*x)
    else:
        print("Please try again!")
        return

        
x = square_non(5)
```

As you can see I do use return after the 'else' statement exactly for the reason why your code was wrong, to terminate the code.

As also was mentioned by a comment earlier, you can append the result into a list:

```
def square_non(n):

squared_list = []

for x in range(0, 21):
    
    if x < n:
        x = (x * x)
        squared_list.append(x)
    else:
        print("Please try again!")
        break
return squared_list
    

        
x = square_non(10)
print(x)
```

So the list is stored now in X, and you can use it. I mentioned this because it's a great way to understand what return does:

1. Terminate the execution of a Loop
2. Return a value, data..basically something that then you can store it in a variable (if you don't do this, the function would return None)